# HTML: Resize font to fit parent

Tags: html, text, fonts, resize, percentage

Is there a way to resize the font of a text if it breaks default parameters, or is there a way to set the font as a percentage to the parent?

```
<table  border='2' width='100'>
  <tr>
    <td width='25%'>
<!-- 
        can I do something to resize 
        the font to font in the cell?
--> 
      <label font='100%'>   
      How-To-Resize-Only-Text
      </label>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It is not the question, but I do recommend you to use CSS for styling and not their html attribute equivalents. ( table td { width: 25%; } etc)

Comment: Seconded—styles should always go in CSS and not in/through HTML

Comment: OK thank you i get on CSS right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `em` unit of measurement can be applied to children elements, and makes a relative measurement from the parent's `font-size` value (the default is `16px`).

Therefore, if you set `font-size: 20px;` on a parent element, and `font-size: 0.5em;` on a child element, the child element's font size will be 50% of the parent's, or 10px. You can also use `em` for width and height.

http://www.impressivewebs.com/understanding-em-units-css/